# Add shadow around text plotted with ggmap, ggplot and geom_sf_text

Tags: r, google-maps, ggplot2, text, r-sf

I need to add a shadow around text plotted using ggmap. By shadow I mean a thin white border around `point1`,`point2` and `point3`. Is there a way to do this?

## Make polygon and points

```
library(tibble); library(sf); library(dplyr); library(ggmap); library(ggplot2)

lon <- c(-2.28693776739262, -2.28775699708943, -2.28703948292762, -2.29244089927134, -2.29166515832837, -2.30186223039892, -2.30309391144779, -2.3056785372324, -2.30317524849752, -2.29377665148526, -2.28749981389358, -2.28693776739262)
lat <- c(55.8178060589878, 55.8176446224019, 55.8143145424301, 55.8134429653489, 55.8125449362038, 55.8111356982306, 55.8143414682509, 55.8151103263674, 55.8178015760052, 55.8220786729108, 55.8200414980507, 55.8178060589878)

df <- tibble(lon, lat)

poly <- df %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326) %>%
  summarise(geometry = st_combine(geometry)) %>%
  st_cast("POLYGON")

lon <- c(-2.290673, -2.297313, -2.298313)
lat <- c(55.815681, 55.818586, 55.814384)

df <- tibble(lon, lat)

poly_points <- df %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326) %>%
  summarise(geometry = st_combine(geometry)) %>%
  st_cast("POINT")

poly_points$name <- c("point1","point2","point3")

poly_points %>% 
  st_combine %>% 
  st_centroid -> 
  poly_points_centroid
```

## Plot using ggmap

```
map <- get_map(location = st_coordinates(poly_points_centroid), zoom = 15, maptype = "satellite")

ggmap(map, extent = "device", legend = "right") +
  geom_sf(data=poly, color='green', inherit.aes = FALSE, fill = NA, size = 1.5) +
  geom_sf_text(data=poly_points, aes(label = name), inherit.aes = FALSE, show.legend = FALSE, size = 4, color = "red") +
  theme_nothing() +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(0.16, 3.8, 1, 1, "cm"))
```

[image]

Comment: `geom_shadowtext()` from the `shadowtext` package is my go-to when I need a halo around text in `ggplot2`.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from Leroy Tyron's suggested {shadowtext}, you could write your own function like so:

```
geom_text_etched <- function(col_shadow = 'white', nudge = .01, ...){
    list2env(list(...), envir = environment())
    list(geom_text(mapping,
                   ## set shadow params:
                   col = col_shadow,
                   nudge_x = nudge,
                   nudge_y = -nudge,
                   alpha = .6,
                   fontface = fontface
                   ),
         geom_text(mapping)
         )
}
```

```
iris |>
    ggplot() +
    geom_text_etched(mapping = aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, label = abbreviate(Species)),
                     nudge = .01, fontface = 'bold'
                     ) +
    theme_dark()
```

(admittedly, this is more for the fun of it than the quality)

[image: shadowed text]